# Ajax image page transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, transition

I just saw a really cool page transition on Behance where you click a image and it just expands to a new div (I think) with a with of 50%. Can someone explain to me how to make this work or have an example? Transition here:

https://vimeo.com/162486588

Comment: Sounds like one of any of 1000s of [lightbox's](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=jquery+lightbox)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [css transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions) if you like. Check the [example](https://jsfiddle.net/b2gv5yny/13/) that I wrote for you.

```css
.normal {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: 10%;
    height: auto;
    transition: width 2s, height 2s;
}

.transition {
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Basically they work by defining 'start' values (in our case width & height inside `.normal`) and also a definition of how to make the transition and what properties to apply it to (in our case `width` and `height` with 2s duration each).

If you now add a class to the element that has the properties with different values (in our case `.transition`), they'll be animated to the new value.

To complete the example, I also added some text that is faded in after the transition has been completed.

The javascript part is fairly simple: When clicking the image, add the `.transition` class, then wait for 2 seconds (the transition duration) and finally fade in the text.

```js
$('img').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('transition');
    setTimeout(function() {
            $('.text').fadeIn();
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: Hey, that's great. What if the image is in some kid of grid and have a parent with position relative etc?

Comment: Then you can try with some kind of overlay, basically overlaying a div absolute positioned div that has the image at the same position, with the same image starting size and transforming it up to the size you need. This goes in the direction of a lightbox, as @freedomn-m mentioned in the comment above.